# Minimizing area of track - Differentiable Calc

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

So I tried this problem and I'm not sure how they got 20m for the radius

[image: Link to image]

Comment: Please do not use snapshots to post your question.

Comment: Start by writing the perimeter equation, then use $x=f(r)$ and plug it into the formula for the area. Then the area will be just a function of $r$.

Comment: @Andrei I found the equation for A, the constraint for the perimeter, as well as solved for A'(x) and found that r = 200/pi. I am just really confused where you get 20 as the radius of the semicircles from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found the maximum of the function that gives the area. Notice that with that radius, you get $x=0$.

Think of a similar, maybe simpler problem: find the minimum and maximum of $x^2$ in the $[1,4]$ interval. $(x^2)'=2x=0$ means $x=0$. But $x$ is not in the given interval. Does that mean that $x^2$ does not have a minimum or maximum in that range? The answer is no. You will need to check the boundaries of the interval as well. For $x^2$ you get $1^2=1$ at one end, and $4^2=16$ at the other. $x^2$ is always increasing in that interval, so the minimum is $1$ at $x=1$, and the maximum is $16$ at $x=4$.

Can you solve now your problem?

Comment: That makes sense, but what would the domain for my problem be in terms of r. [20 , ?], would it be [20,100/pi), since the 2pir = 400 - 2(100) at most.

Comment: One limit is $r>20$. The other limit is given by the perimeter and the requirement that $x>100$: $$2x+2\pi r=400\\r=\frac{200-x}\pi$$When $x=100$, the radius is $100/\pi$. If you increase $x$, the radius will decrease. So the maximum $r$ is at $x=100$.